# How to use auto increment index in Tarantool?

Tags: tarantool

I made auto increment index:

```lua
box.space.metric:create_index('primary', {
        parts = {{'id', 'unsigned'}},
        sequence = true,
})
```

Then I try to pass nil in *id* field:

```
metric.id = nil
```

When I try insert this values, I catch error:

```
Tuple field 1 type does not match one required by operation: expected unsigned
```

What value do I have to pass for autoincrement field?

Second questions. If I use tarantool-cluster with few instances (for ex. cartridge-application based), is it prove use autoincrement indexes? Will there be a cases that there will be duplicate keys on different instances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to pass `nil`. When you assign `nil`, you erase field. Use `box.NULL` instead.
But better, use some kind of cluster id, which perform well across cluster, instead of autoincrement, which works only inside one node.

For cluster-wide ids I could propose `UUID` or something like `ULID` (for ex from https://github.com/moonlibs/id)